# Creating a topic programmatically in kafka using the Microsoft/CSharpClient-for-Kafka library .NET

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

Hi I was wondering if there is an analogous API in the .NET library for creating a topic, the same way
`AdminUtils.createTopic(zkClient, myTopic, 10, 1, new Properties());`

is available for the java client? Otherwise, how would i go about programmatically creating a topic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no Admin API in the client libraries that would allow you to do this. See [issue #48 on the .NET client's GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/48).

Depending on how you configure your broker (`auto.create.topics.enable`), you can let topics be created automatically once you attach a producer or a consumer to them. The downside to this approach is that you can't easily set up topics with different settings, since they will be set up using the default settings configured in the broker.

A less nice, but currently the only full-featured, way to create topics is to simply call the command-line management tools (e.g. `kafka-topics`) from your code, and pass the settings as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple method like below:

```
private void CraeteTopic(string eventName)
{
    try
    {
        IAdminClient adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(this._consumerConfig).Build();
        TopicSpecification topicSpecification = new TopicSpecification();
        topicSpecification.Name = eventName;
        adminClient.CreateTopicsAsync(new[] { topicSpecification });
    }
    catch (CreateTopicsException createTopicsException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(createTopicsException);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
        throw;
    }
}
```